# Sort table based on ratings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a scenario where i need to sort table based on ratings for which i am using `orderBy` filter

here i could sort by name perfectly ,but i am unable to sort ratings which is again an array

html:

```
<table class="friends">
  <thead>
    <tr class='table-head'>
      <th scope="col"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Candidate Name</a></th>
      <th scope="col" ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4]" ><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="sortType = 'rating'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Round{{a}}</a></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="candidate in aCandidateDetails| orderBy:sortType:sortReverse" class="text-center">
      <td>
        <div>{{candidate.name}}</div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="candidateData in candidate.ratings| orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <div >
        {{candidateData.rating}}
        </div>
        <span ng-if="!candidateData.rating">    - NA -   </span> </td>
      <td data-title="Status">
        <div>{{candidate.interviewStatus}}</div>
      </td>
      <td><a href="" ng-model='candidate' ng-click="fnCandidateFeedbackDetails(candidate.uniqueId,candidate._id)"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
$scope.sortType = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse = false; // set the default sort order
```

I have done a working example as well which has json data 
[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IdyGhhmG56XhnTHOhr9h?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngRepeat` directive creates a *child* `$scope`, so you should use the `Dot Rule` or `controller-as-syntax`:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.sortType = 'name';
$scope.model.sortReverse = false;
```

And modify all those in your view..

See the <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xF55FEl0rSxvGa8k71CQ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: if im using .notation its working good  but the sorting is happening row wise but i need to sort columns like if the rating of b in 1st round is  more it should be on top unlike here 
https://plnkr.co/edit/06BJ5BPf04T8iPTzKbO0?p=preview